# Filereader: Multiple file input ends with only one image as preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, filereader

Trying to figure out how to input multiple files at once and arrange them to divs. In result, only the last image of the array appears.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="imageinput" accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(files)" multiple>
    <div class="cube-layout-1">
        <div id="preview1"></div>
        <div id="preview2"></div>
        <div id="preview3"></div>
        <div id="preview4"></div>
        <div id="preview5"></div>
        <div id="preview6"></div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
        var j=0;

        function counter() {
            j++;
            return j;
        }

        function handleFiles(files) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                var count = counter();
                var preview = document.getElementById("preview"+count);

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload =  (function (preview) {
                    return function () {
                        preview.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";
                    }
                })(preview);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
```

For example, if I choose 3 images at once, the first two divs get an empty background image and only the last div gets the image.
I know it has something to do with the reader.onload event, which triggers only when the loop ends....but how can I achieve what I am aiming for? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check out my code try using it, I solved the Async issue, as I needed to add file name along with the preview.

```
  function readURL(input) {
        var file = document.getElementById("article_file").value;
        console.log(file);
        var originalname = file.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
        console.log(name);
        if (DST()) {
            // Daylight Savings, EDT is UTC-4
            var offset = "-4";
        } else {
            // Not Daylight Savings, EST is UTC-5
            var offset = "-5";
        }
        var today = calcTime(offset);

        var month = today.getMonth() + 1;

        // appends 0 to monthes under 10
        if (month < 10)
            month = "0" + month.toString();

        if ($('table.appendo.image-uploader tbody tr').length > 2)
            $('table.appendo.image-uploader tbody tr').each(function (i, ele) {
                if(i==1)
                {
                     $('#image-preview-path').attr('src','src="/images/tp.gif"');
                     $('#image-path').attr('value','');
                }
                else if (i > 1)
                {
                    $(ele).remove();
                }
            });
        $('.upload-article').attr('name', 'Filedata[]');

        var files = $('#article_file')[0].files;
        var name = [];
        var extension = ['.jpg','jpeg','.gif','.png'];
        var flag = 1;
        name['invalid'] = 'invalid';
        for (var z = 0; z < files.length; z++){
            var ext = (files[z].name.substr(-4)).toLowerCase();
            if($.inArray(ext, extension) != -1){

            } else {
                flag = 2;
            }
        }
        var count = files.length;
        if(count <= '6') {
        if(flag == 1) {
        for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++)
        {

            if (x == 0) {
                var file = files[x];
                var hello = file['name'].replace(/\s/g, '');
                var file_name = hello.replace(/[^.a-z0-9_-\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]_/g, '-');
                name[file['size']] = file_name;
                console.log(files[x]);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                    console.log(e)

                    $('#image-preview-path').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    $('#image-path').attr('value', "/images/uploads/" + today.getFullYear() + "/" + month + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + name[e.total]);

                });
                reader.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                var file = files[x];
                var hello = file['name'].replace(/\s/g, '');
                var file_name = hello.replace(/[^.a-z0-9_-\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]_/g, '-');
                name[file['size']] = file_name;
                console.log(files[x]);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    if ($('table.appendo>tbody:eq(0)>tr').length - 1 > 0)
                        index = $('table.appendo>tbody:eq(0)>tr').length - 1
                    else
                        index = 'invalid';
                    var table = $('table.appendo tbody tr:eq(1)').clone();
                    table.find('img').attr('id', 'image-preview-path');
                    table.find('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    table.find('input').attr('id', 'image-path');
                    table.find('input').attr('value', "/images/uploads/" + today.getFullYear() + "/" + month + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + name[e.total]);
                    $('table.appendo.image-uploader tbody').append(table);

                });
                reader.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
      } else {
          alert('Not a valid file extension.');
          $('#article_file').val("");
        } 
      } else {
          alert('You have attempted to queue too many files.\nYou may select six file.');
          $('#article_file').val("");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution insted of:

```
return function () { preview.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";}
```

it should be:

```
return function (e) { preview.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + e.target.result + ")";}
```